# Query para sacar datos de dos tablas con dos posibles campos de relación

Tags: oracle, sql

voy a intentar explicarlo de la mejor manera posible.

Tengo dos tablas, una tabla de departamentos y otra de empleados.
En la tabla 1 tengo departamentos principales que "cuelgan" de un departamento raíz, y tengo departamentos que cuelgan de departamentos principales, los campos importantes serían:
-cd_departamento
-cd_departamento_padre

en la tabla 2 los empleados tienen el cd_departamento al que pertenezcan, que es foreign key de cd_departamentos de la tabla 1. Puede ser principal o no.

La query que necesito tendría que sacar todos los datos de los empleados dado un cd_departamento, pero tendría que sacar los empleados de ese departamento Y de todos los departamentos que cuelguen de el, es decir, que si el departamento 2 cuelga del 1, y yo digo que quiero todos los empleados del departamento 1, me tendrían que salir también los empleados cuyo cd_departamento es 2.

Espero que se entienda lo que necesito.
Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por tu pregunta, entiendo que los departamentos se ordenan en dos niveles (por ejemplo depto 1, depto 2, etc.., es la variable `cd_departamento_padre`) y vinculados a ellos hay otro nivel (del depto 1 dependen el sub-depto A, B y C; del depto 2 dependen el sub-depto D y E, por ejemplo, es la variable `cd_departamento`).

Y que en la tabla de empleados cada uno tiene adjudicado un sub-depto (el A, B o C por ejemplo).

Y el pedido es traer todos los empleados de, por ejemplo, el depto 1 (que incluye los sub-deptos `A, B y C`).

En este caso se me ocurre esto:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLA2 TT
LEFT JOIN TABLA1 T ON T.CD_DEPARTAMENTO=TT.CD_DEPARTAMENTO
WHERE T.CD_DEPARTAMENTO_PADRE = '1'
```

Comment: A pesar de lo complicado que era explicarlo lo has cogido a la perfección y ha funcionado, muchas gracias

Comment: Me alegro que haya servido!

Comment: Me acabo de dar cuenta de un problemilla, y es que la consulta solo saca los sub-dptos que cuelgan directamente del departamento padre que indiques, no saca toda la "rama". Es decir, siguiendo tu ejemplo, saca los deptos A,B y C, pero no saca D y E.

Comment: Hola Sergio! Saca solo los A,B y C porque son los que "dependen" del depto padre 1 y esa es la condición que pusimos en la consulta (WHERE T.CD_DEPARTAMENTO_PADRE = '1').  Si quieres que traiga más sub deptos puedes agregarlos en el where